# COLLATION_NAME change mysql amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, collation, amazon-rds

I am using **Amazon RDS mysql 5.6**. my problem is that my database is not case sensitive.
Ex. I am unable to insert 'Deepesh' and 'deepesh' values in primary key column.

as per the on line solution we need to change the collation_server.
my current **collation_server** is **utf8_general_ci** and CHARACTER_SET_NAME is utf8.

pls suggest how can I change this and what will be the impact on system,
my DB size is 500GB this time.

Comment: I got this solution:- "ALTER TABLE `test` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;". Please suggest what will be impact on the database after this, My table size is 200 mb the select is 100 TPS, insert/update is 50 TPS.